# Does it make sense to create same connection object but different session objects

Tags: java, database, session, jms, activemq-classic

I read [this ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/multiple-consumers-on-a-queue.html) and got question about creating/using connection and session objects for ActiveMQ, now if I create one connection object which I use among several consumers and each consumer having different session object then would there be any performance difference compared to when I create one connection and one session object? I don't think so. (*don't think from multi-threading issues perspective*)

I think if I have one connection object then it doesn't matter whether I have one session object or more than one session object for all consumer because communication will be sequential as I cannot use same connection object while it is doing a communication for any consumer.

I think better approach is to create a pool of connection objects and separate session object for each consumer, like that there would be performance boost?

I think this is true in general as well, like what happens in case of database communication.

Answer (score 0):

This is depends on how many consumers, messages, memory, cpu you have.

> The JMS contract is that only 1 session is used by one thread at once
>   - which if you're using consumers means that only 1 consumer can receive messages at once if using the same session

Each consumer must have a session after that if you have many consumers for example 100 it is better to use a PooledConnectionFactory to fix a limit of number of connections to not overhead Ressources.

If you have 10 consumers you can use 1 connection without decreasing performances.

You can do some tests to compare results with your resources.